# Typing persian/arbic inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, translation

I developed a website with WordPress. I got an open-source Javascript code in English that converts units online. I just wanted to translate its items to Persian. For example in a piece of that code shown below, I changed "Kilogram" to "کیلوگرم". but at frontend, it displays as

" & # 1 7 0 5 ; & # 1 7 4 0 ; & # 1 6 0 4 ; & # 1 6 0 8 ; & # 1 7 1 1 ; & # 1 5 8 5 ; & # 1 6 0 5 ; "  (space added manually between chracters to prevent auto decode/encode by stackoverfloow)

some parts of the main code:

```
var weight0={"carats":["Carat",5000],"grams":["Gram",1000],"kilograms":["Kilogram",1],"milligrams":["Milligram",1000000],'
```

What should I do to display it correctly?
(I'm not professional at JS. Thanks)

Comment: Escape the non-Latin characters using an online tool like https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Comment: Something in your process is erratically encoding your text into html entities (i.e. as if it is html and can't display those characters natively) while it's not being displayed as html. Or it is encoded *twice*. If you look at the webpage's source (right click > view source in your browser) do you see `&#1705;` there, or `&amp;#1705;` ? But the best way would be to just include the characters literally. Be sure to use unicode (utf-8 encoding) for your content as well as in the html head.

Comment: Thanks
I've found the soloution.
persian chracters should be used as unicode (like \u0627)
Full list:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet